# Risk of virus image

Tags: java, image, base64

I am maybe asking a dumb question but I would like to be sure as my app is almost finished and I don't want to face some issue with viruses in the future

I have an app written in angular2 and a backend in java.
People can change their profile picture.

From my frontend I encode the picture in base64 and send it with a post to my rest api.

- Server check the size of the base64 and reject it if it reached a certain size (but I also have a maxPostSize of 2MB in tomcat by default)
- The base64 is then decoded with library net.iharder which transform it in bytearray
  http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/
- Once it is done I check if the file is a picture (and resize it as well) by creating a  BufferedImage with

  ```
  ImageIO.read(ByteArrayInputStream)
  ```

  If it does not correspond to an image it returns null So I don't see the risk here as well.
- Once it is done I store the picture in my server.

Any profile who consult the profile with picture will receive a base64 encoded image (corresponding to the uploaded one) and it will be displayed in an basic

```
<img src="myBase64"/>
```

Only JPG and PNG are allowed

My question is this one: Is there any risk for my server or for the end users if a guy send a file containg a virus? Or am I safe with the ImageIO reader.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There have been buffer overrun attacks against standard image libraries.  For example the PNG / JPEG header is written in a way that overflows an expected size.

Answer (score 1):

If you store anything sent to you and send it back unchanged, then anything can happen. Just because ImageIO can read the image, doesn't mean that there's not something compromising in there.

However, if you resize the image, and use that, then there's pretty much no chance of anything surviving that as you're creating a brand new image from raw image bytes. JPG and (I guess) PNG files can contain meta data that's not part of the image, and those can potentially be vectors for exploits. But by creating a new image from the raw image data, you implicitly strip all of that.

Comment: Right.  It can infect your own server but not your customers.